# Strapi returns 404 error when fetching data from Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, content-type, strapi

I'm using this Gatsby starter : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter
as I was looking for something to introduce myself both to Gatsby and to Material UI.

My first objective was to change Netlify CMS for Strapi CMS, I've followed these steps:

1. Removed Netlify plugin, both from *gatsby-config.js*, *package.json* and make uninstall.
2. Added Strapi to the project:

   1. *npm install --save gatsby-source-strapi*
      and add the plugin to *gatsby-config.js*

Here's how I added the Strapi plugin to *gatsby-config.js*:

[image: Strapi plugin]

And here's the error I'm getting:

[image: Strapi 404 status code]

I think it might be related to Gatsby not being able to contact the remote Strapi server, any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so this was a dumb mistake that I just couldn't see: after trying different solutions, which didn't work, I realized that Strapi was trying to fetch data from *http://167.172.32.171//posts?_limit=1000*, so my problem was that I had an extra / in the URL I indicated to the plugin.